# FancyBox › Adding fullscreen toggle button to dynamic gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a series of a tags, each in a list item, and each item launches a gallery. The 'href' value references a javascript file (href="javascript:;"). I cant figure out how to add a full screen toggle button for a gallery in which each clicked item launches another sub gallery of images (with thumbnails on the bottom). There is an image attached of what the gallery currently looks like.

Here is an example of my list items in the HTML:::

```
      ...<ul>
      <li><a id="ui_1" href="javascript:;">
          <img src="img/ui_1.jpg" alt="" />
      </a>
      </li>...
```

Here is corresponding javascript for one a tag. (I already have functioning helper: thumbnails)[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
            $("#ui_1").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
            {
                href : 'img/ui_1a.jpg',
                // title : 'My title'
            }, {
                href : 'img/ui_1b.jpg',
                // title : 'My title'
            }, {
                href : 'img/ui_1C.jpg',
                // title : 'My title'
            }, {
                href : 'img/ui_1d.jpg',
                // title : 'My title'
            }, {
                href : 'img/ui_1e.jpg',
                // title : 'My title'
            }, {
                href : 'img/ui_1f.jpg',
                // title : 'My title'
            },


            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use fancybox `buttons` extended functionality (which includes the fullscreen *toggle* button), then just add it to the `helpers` option like

```
helpers : {
    thumbs : {
        width: 75,
        height: 50
    },
    buttons : {}
}
```

Of course, you also have to load the proper js and css files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{your correct path}/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{your correct path}/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
```